# Add tow discount in sales in odoo

Tags: inheritance, odoo, discount

I want to add two discounts،first discount and second discount  in the customer class, so that when I select a specific person in the sales module, the two types of discounts that I added to him will appear to me previously.

I'm trying to do that, but I can't because it doesn't work related between the customer and the sales because I made inheritance for the customer and I can't make control for the tow discount